# How to search for a binary sequence on Windows?

Tags: windows, search, file-search, binary-files

I want to search for a binary file and all I know is that it contains a certain sequence of bytes. What tool can help me find it?

Comment: Forgive me for being curious, but was this a part of a magic number?

Comment: @sammyg I don't remember, it was 4 years go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way of doing that with [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/). You check the box at Options > Content > Regular expressions, and then use them to specify your binary string:

Sample 3-character binary string in RegEx

```
\xC1\x8F\xC1
```

You can do the same with other tools like [WindowsGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/)
Update: Note that WindowsGrep is no longer supported, but it is still downloadable [here](https://download.cnet.com/Windows-Grep/3000-2351_4-75805915.html)

Comment: WindowsGrep seems not active anymore, check  https://sourceforge.net/projects/grepwin/ too.

Comment: I don't think this works with Windows Grep.